# Terraform GCP: Remote execute PowerShell in Windows instance on create

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have made a simple Terraform manifest that successfully initiates a Windows 2016 instance in GCP. As a next step I would like to execute a Powershell script to further configure and install software in the Windows instance.

I can not for my life find any example on how to execute a remote script through Terraform in a Windows GCP instance. For Linux instances it seems pretty straight forward, but how is it supposed to be done for Windows? Does anyone know any examples?

Any thoughts or ideas are much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the metadata to init your script like this:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
 project = "your_project"
 zone = "us-central1-c"
 name = "tf-windows-script"
 machine_type = "f1-micro"
 boot_disk {
   initialize_params {
     image = "windows-server-2008-r2-dc-v20180710"
   }
 }
 network_interface {
   network = "default"
   access_config {
   }
 }
 metadata {
    windows-startup-script-url = "gs://your_bucket/startup.ps1"
  }
}
```

In my test the init script works without problems,

Here you can check the documentation of [how to provide a startup script for Windows instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances)

Comment: Thanks @miguelfrancisco85

I use `windows-startup-script-ps1`, and can see in Windows application log that `GCEMetadataScripts: Finished running startup scripts.`. However I can not see anything being executed. 

In my example I have used a simple script that creates a folder. Do you have any thoughts on why my script does not execute?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you have an error inside your script. This is what I'm using https://storage.googleapis.com/windows-script-mnunez/startup.ps1

Comment: It's actually more likely permissions on the bucket. This part confuses me a bit. 
Which user is actually making the access to the bucket? 
I tried giving the service account, that runs the Terraform connection, owner access to the bucket.Still I get 403 in the Windows event log. 

`GCEMetadataScripts: ERROR main.go:320: error downloading script: GET "https://storage.googleapis.com/qsefw-bucket/startup.ps1", bad status: 403 Forbidden`

Comment: GCE documentation confirms that windows-startup-script-url has to point to a public file, which does not work for me as I need to pass in some user credentials

Comment: It's not only to the bucket, you can control the access to the file/object  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch-examples